Running command 'cat /proc/<pid>/stat | cut -d" " -f29' to get stack pointer , is always showing stack pointer as zero
Iam trying to get the stack pointer of some thread using the /proc//stat, whenever i run the command,cat /proc/<pid>/stat | cut -d" " -f29 i end up getting zero, but when i run  sudo cat /proc/<pid>/stack i do end up getting a value
[<0>] worker_thread+0xb7/0x390
[<0>] kthread+0x134/0x150
[<0>] ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40

not sure this is happening, any ideas why the stack pointer keeps being zero, thanks.

The fields are intentionally zeroed out. Quote fs/proc/array.c:
/*
 * esp and eip are intentionally zeroed out.  There is no
 * non-racy way to read them without freezing the task.
 * Programs that need reliable values can use ptrace(2).
 *
 * The only exception is if the task is core dumping because
 * a program is not able to use ptrace(2) in that case. It is
 * safe because the task has stopped executing permanently.
 */

This zeroing out can be seen at line 489 in the same file from the current Linux 6.10-rc2:
vsize = eip = esp = 0;


so is it saying that i cant use the /proc//stat to constantly check the sp of a running process, because it is always going to be zero ?

Yes, that is correct. As the quote states, a program can use ptrace(2) system call to obtain reliable values. GDB can also attach to a process (using -p as root) to debug it.

I updated the answer with the exact line preceding the comment, which zeroes out the three local variables.
